# How to make Bootstrap modal content side by side?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Newbie to bootstrap.I followed the bootstrap 4 documentation to create a simple modal.
[Bootstrap 4 modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/)

And created a modal with two parts - Part 1 and Part 2 separated by a `<hr>` tag.

I couldn't succeed in putting the two parts - Part 1 and Part 2 side by side.

Link to modal:

[CodePen modal](https://codepen.io/thorstorm/pen/VwvWXyv)

Here is my sample modal:

```
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Launch demo modal</button>
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form>
                <h4>Part 1</h4>
                                    <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                            <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                            <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="inputAddress2">Address 2</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                            <label for="inputCity">City</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                            <label for="inputState">State</label>
                                            <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                                                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                                                <option>...</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                            <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">Check me out <span class="form-check-sign">
                <span class="check"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                <hr>
                <h4>Part 2</h4>
                                    <form>
                                        <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="inputAddress2">Address 2</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label for="inputCity">City</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                <label for="inputState">State</label>
                                                <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                                                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                                                    <option>...</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                                <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">Check me out <span class="form-check-sign">
                  <span class="check"></span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal -->
```

Is there any article to refer to or any suggestions to proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">first side</div>
    <div class="col-6">second side</div>
  </div>
<form>
```

And also you should change your modal width.

Comment: Should i add inside the form

Comment: Where should end the `</div>`